# Best way how to replace <b></b> tags from localization strings by bold text in labels

Tags: ios, swift

I have in some localization strings tags like  and I have to replace normal text with bold in labels.

I have for example something like this

> < b>ENTER< /b> ACCOUNT DETAILS

and I need this

> **ENTER** ACCOUNT DETAILS

I am looking for best way how to do it. If it helps, I can replace  with something else, for example $ or something.

I have now something like you can see below, but its little bit creepy and its not working, when I have more than one  tags in one label.

```
extension UILabel {
@IBInspectable var localizable: String {
    get {
        return self.text ?? ""
    }
    set {
        self.text = NSLocalizedString(newValue, comment: "")
        if let value = text {
            if let firstRange = value.range(of: "<b>"),
                let secondRange = value.range(of: "</b>") {
                let startPos = value.distance(from: value.startIndex, to: firstRange.lowerBound)
                let endPos = value.distance(from: value.startIndex, to: secondRange.upperBound)
                let stringtoReplace = value.substring(from: startPos, to: endPos)
                let newString = (stringtoReplace.replacingOccurrences(of: "<b>", with: "")).replacingOccurrences(of: "</b>", with: "")
                self.text = (text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "<b>", with: ""))?.replacingOccurrences(of: "</b>", with: "")
                if let attributedText = self.attributedText,
                    let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: self.font.pointSize) {
                    let attributedStringToChange = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
                    attributedStringToChange.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: (attributedText.string as NSString).range(of: newString))
                    self.attributedText = attributedStringToChange
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Look through the answers of the duplicate for versions in Swift.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28416599/2303865

Comment: I soved it by https://cocoapods.org/pods/Atributika

Comment: Solution with latest Swift version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667603/nsstring-strip-out-b-b-and-make-an-attributed-string-with-color-for-that-se